# Windows PowerShell Import-module

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, group-policy, import-module

On my computer in PowerShell the command

```
import-module GroupPolicy
```

fails with

```
import-module <<<<  GroupPolicy
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (GroupPolicy:String) [Import-Module],     FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I cannot find a solution to this issue, according to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx) this is the way to go.

Background info:

A colleague developed a Windows PowerShell Script on his Windows 7 32 bit. He installed RSAT. The first command in this script is "import-module GroupPolicy". On his Win7x86 the command works fine, from the command line and when running the script as a whole.

I'm trying to work on his script but I'm using a Windows 7 64 bit system. I also installed RSAT (Windows6.1-KB958830-x64-RefreshPkg.msu). But on my machine the command fails like described above. I cannot find any important differences regarding the content of C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

Googling wasn't much help either. There were Postings about PowerShellV1 and running PowerShells x86 version on Win7x64, but neither helped solving this.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards,
T.

Comment: Edit: I found the module "GroupPolicy" on my colleagues computer in "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules". I can now copy this to my local filesystem, but this doen't answer the question why this module is not being installed with RSAT. I still wonder if I'm doing something wrong here or if I installed RSAT without clicking the necessary options...

Comment: You could use "Import-Module PhysicalPath". For example, "Import-Module F:\FolderName\ModuleName"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention *installing* RSAT, but not *enabling* any of it's features. So I suspect you had not done anything in that regard...?

If that is the case, got to control panel -> programs and features -> turn windows features on or off:

[image]

I suspect enabling marked option should do the job...